# Inner layout bigger than the parent one

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts. The inner one wraps its contents for height and matches parent for width.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytMoreInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lytMoreInfoButtons"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <!-- OTHER VIEWS HERE -->

             </LinearLayout>

             <!-- OTHER VIEWS HERE -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

The outer layout, instead, need to be animated for its height, kinda open to show its content. To do that, I use a value animator that change the height of the outer layout. The animation works correctly.

The problem is that the views inside the inner layout are stretched during the animation, because the inner layout is resized together with the outer layout during the animation.

So my question is, is there a way to specify the inner layout to wrap its content (for height), regardless the size of the outer layout?

Comment: So are you doing animation just to stretch the innerlayout? Post your whole xml.

Comment: The whole xml is a bit long and useless for this problem. However I just want to keep the inner layout height fixed so that its content will not be stretched.

Answer (score 0):

> Its not the proper solution to make height/width fix. As it will
>   varies with device.  You can use scrollview for that.